# jQuery tabs in IE 9 not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have this simple js tabs.

Here is the html :

```
<div class="product-collateral">
    <div class="tab">
      <h3 class="product_tabs_agenda">Tab 1</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_agenda_contents">
      <p>Tab1 Content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <h3 class="product_tabs_terms">Terms and Conditions</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="product-tabs-content" id="product_tabs_terms_contents">
      <p>Some terms and conditions</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the java is as follow:

```
< script type = "text/javascript" > $jQ('.product-collateral .tab h3').wrapAll('<ul class="product-tabs"></ul>').wrap('<li></li>');
$jQ('.product-collateral .product-tabs li').each(function(index) {
    $jQ(this).attr('id', $jQ(this).find('h3').attr('class'));
    if (index == 0) $jQ(this).addClass('active');
});
//<![CDATA[
Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
    initialize: function(selector) {
        var self = this;
        $$(selector + ' h3').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
    },

    initTab: function(el) {
        el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
        if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
            this.showContent(el);
        }
        el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
    },

    showContent: function(a) {
        var li = $(a.parentNode),
            ul = $(li.parentNode);
        ul.select('li', 'ol').each(function(el) {
            var contents = $(el.id + '_contents');
            if (el == li) {
                el.addClassName('active');
                contents.show();
            } else {
                el.removeClassName('active');
                contents.hide();
            }
        });
    }
}
new Varien.Tabs('.product-tabs');
//]]>
< /script>
```

The tabs are working fine apart from internet expoler. I was trying to find the bug in the code - unfortunately unsuccessfully.

Any hepl much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Dom

Comment: Found this in google http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/253155/ it might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two $ when selecting you H3...

```
initialize: function(selector) {
        var self = this;
        $$(selector + ' h3').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
    },
```

Comment: That is now day two when I am trying to figure out why this script is not working. Any help please?

Comment: Change the line above $$(selector + ' h3').each(this.initTab.bind(this)); to $(selector + ' h3').each(this.initTab.bind(this));

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this line is the culprit? You have 2 `$$`

```
$$(selector + ' h3').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
```

Comment: This is what I initially thought, im not sure why is is there but without it the tabs are completely breaks

Answer (score 0):

My tabs kept disappearing in IE 9.

They happened to be nested in a table cell. Once I took them out of the cell the they didn't have the IE 9 issue anymore.

Comment: Well, that's not the case in the original question.